# I have an array within an array but cannot figure out how to access the interior elements

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an excerpt of my code. I am going through gathered data and inputting fId and distance into friendObj. Then after that data is put in I want to put the entire friendObj into another array called friendArry. I cannot seem to figure out how to access the individual elements of the interior array from the outer array. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Also on a side note, my intention is to eventually get all of the friendObj and sort them based on distance. How could I do that?

```
$friendObj = array('id' => $fId, 'distance' => $distanceFromYou);

        $friendsArry;
        array_push($friendsArry, $friendObj);
        echo "Test2: ". $friendsArray[0][id]."<br />";
        echo "<br />";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to declare `$friendsArry` as an `array()` before you attempt to push to it:

```
$friendsArry = array();
```

Then to retrieve the value by using the key `0` and subkey `id`.

```
echo $friendsArry[0]['id'];
```

To further sort the array, you can push your array distances to a separate array, then sort it using [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Comment: If my solution solved your problem, please be sure to accept my answer so others having the same issue can find it.